# Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Homebrewing Stack Exchange](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: When you say "run a few Google searches", are you attempting to determine whether the exact homebrewing.stackexchange.com question/answer being evaluated is in the results, or whether the effectively same question and answer comes up?  The first would show the effectiveness of SEO, and the second would show the interestingness of the question and the accuracy of the answer.

Comment: I think it's both - if the answer comes up in the first page then that's a good thing, but if not/in addition, compare the given answer to other sites. Although what do you search for - the question text? That's sure to give a reliable hit.

Comment: Graduation review verdict: this site is not yet ready for graduation. Community is becoming somewhat more active, but still very small and in need of more engagement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Using pine in beer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/using-pine-in-beer)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Online hops reference](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9877/online-hops-reference)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Sanitize the bottle capper?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9998/sanitize-the-bottle-capper)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Pectic Enzyme in Secondary?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10035/pectic-enzyme-in-secondary)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [How do conventional foods effect kombucha brewing?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10047/how-do-conventional-foods-effect-kombucha-brewing)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How long must an ale be conditioned in bottles outside of the fridgerator?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9972/how-long-must-an-ale-be-conditioned-in-bottles-outside-of-the-fridgerator)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Unusual flavourings](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9934/unusual-flavourings)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Specific gravity is the wrong way](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10017/specific-gravity-is-the-wrong-way)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Variations in Recycled Crown Bottles](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9894/variations-in-recycled-crown-bottles)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Fitering BIAB wort](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9945/fitering-biab-wort)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)